# Place Button with input text with css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

[image: [like this]]

how do I make input text and buttons like this with CSS ? or vuetify js

Comment: Please put the code you have tried so far into your question and describe what isn't working correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the CSS you looking for.

```css
.parent-box{
  width:fit-content;
  background:#26376B;
}
.text-box{
  border:1px solid #CACACA;
  padding:5px 10px;
  min-width:300px;
}
.btn{
  padding:5px 20px;
  width:100px;
  color:#fff;
  border:none;
  background-color:#26376B;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.common{
  outline:none;
  border-radius:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box common">
  <input class="text-box common" type="text" placeholder="Chassis Number">
  <button class="btn common">Check</button>
</div>
```

if you only want the numbers to input then use `type="number"` in `<input type="text">`

Comment: helpfull :) tq ..

Comment: hi @kurisu , If this answers your question then please mark this as ACCEPTED by clicking the check icon.
If it doesn't then tell us in your question what exactly you are looking for.