# I want to create a text field in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbCfI.png

I want to create a text field in vuetify but the button can't be made like this? and for the height but it can't it be changed? I've tried several times to change the height and it doesn't work

I already have the css but it's hard to use on vuetify

```
.parent-box{
  width:fit-content;
  background:#26376B;
}
.text-box{
  border:1px solid #CACACA;
  padding:5px 10px;
  min-width:300px;
}
.btn{
  padding:5px 20px;
  width:100px;
  color:#fff;
  border:none;
  background-color:#26376B;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.common{
  outline:none;
  border-radius:50px;
}

<div class="parent-box common">
  <input class="text-box common" type="text" placeholder="Chassis Number">
  <button class="btn common">Check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using Vuetify components at all? The input and button in the image do not fit Material Design principles. You can read more about it here: https://material.io/components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place Button with input text with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389576/place-button-with-input-text-with-css)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Problem Statement:** Want to create the text field with button in Vuetify.

**Solution:**

HTML:

```html
<v-app id="app">

  <v-container>
  
    <v-text-field
      label="Chassis Number"
      color="primary"
      v-model="input"
      @keypress.enter="show">
  
       <template v-slot:append>
  
          <v-btn
            depressed 
            tile
            color="primary"
            class="ma-0"
            @click="show">
          
            show
            
          </v-btn>
        
      </template>
        
    </v-text-field>
      
  </v-container>
  
</v-app>
```

Vue.js:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    input: ''
  },
  methods: {
    show(){
      alert(this.input)
    }
  }
})
```

**Output:**

[image: The wanted output]

Comment: Please be mindful of your formatting. You received several downvotes from members of the community because, prior to my edit, it wasn't possible to read your full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar can be done this way:

```
...
<v-container>
  <v-layout wrap class="parent-box common">
    <v-text-field
       class="text-field__styled"
       outlined
       rounded
       dense
       color="#26376B"
       placeholder="Chassis Number"
       height="27"
       hide-details
    ></v-text-field>
    <button class="btn__styled">Check</button>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>

...

<style>
.parent-box {
  background: #26376B;
  width: 400px;
}

.common {
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.text-field__styled {
  background: #fff;
}

.btn__styled {
  color: #fff; 
  width: 100px;
}

.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
  min-height: auto !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
</style>
```

Take a look into [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/yLzXRrP).

Many styles are customizable in vuetify via **props**. But by default vuetify inspired by Material Design in contrast to your example, and it's not so easy to customize default styles. Possibly it'd be better in your case to apply some of vuetify themes before using this library.